# Moving directory to a new drive

Tags: partitioning, mount

Wondering if anyone Linux users would be able to help me.

Few things:

My 1TB is /dev/sdb2

My 2TB is /dev/sdc

My current Media directory is /FileServer

I would like to move /FileServer to /dev/sdc contents and all. how would I go and do something like this?

Fstab file if it helps at all

/dev/sdb2 /FileServer ntfs defaults 0 0

/dev/sdc /backup ext3 defaults 0 0

I don't have anything in backup currently. and Willing to delete if it apart of the process

---

```
lsblk -f
NAME    FSTYPE  LABEL   UUID    MOUNTPOINT
loop0   squashfs    /snap/core/7396 loop1   squashfs    /snap/core/7270
sda
├─sda1
└─sda2  ext4    4b7435dd-e74c-4aef-95ae-94591c8fef63    /
sdb
├─sdb1  vfat    6BB0-42CC
└─sdb2  ntfs    Media   3468548E6854512A    /FileServer
sdc
└─sdc1
```

Comment: Hi Lionel and wellcome to AskUbuntu. I'm looking forward to answer your question. I can see two different paths how to mount the devices. Let me know in the commnet if you prefere to use the terminal or a Desktop enviremnet (f.e. GNOME, KDE or xfce) so I can give you a workthough.

Comment: @BobaFit I'm currently running Ubuntu server 18.04 LTS and currently SSHed into the box from the main PC. So terminal. Thank you!!

Comment: Why not just use copy/paste? Also note, /dev/sdc should be /dev/sdc1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given from you `lsblk -f` infromation, I can see you there is no filesystem on /dev/sdc1 yet. So you need to

```
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdc1 -L FileServer -d /FileServer
```

The option `-d /FileServer` copeis all the files from  the folder into the filesystem. `-L FileServer` gives you a label for the new filesystem.

With `sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /a/empty/folder` you can mount the filesystem to check the result. `sudo umount /dev/sdc1` does an unmount.

After enter these commands, your new fs is mounted on your direcotry.

```
 sudo umount /dev/sdb2
 sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /FileServer
```

In the end you should reconfigure the fstab file, so that the ext4 partition will be mounted on your directory.

```
/dev/sdc1 /FileServer ext4 defaults 0 0
```

The line with sdb2 you can an a `#` to make it a comment

```
#/dev/sdb2 /FileServer ntfs defaults 0 0
```

Then after each reboot the system will mount your filesystem correctly as you wish.

Comment: Currently waiting for 700GB+ to transfer. I had to do `mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdc1 -L FileServer -d /FileServer` for the first command to work. But thank you for the help! Definitely helped me learn some new things about linux!

Comment: Let it do it's thing over night, and it seems everything is working like it should. Thank you again sir!!

Answer (score 1):

rsync should work for you, try something like:

```
$ rsync -av /FileServer /backup
```

It won't delete contents of your source. Once successful you can simply remove your mount and format as needed.

Comment: i think `-a` is not a good option, since one copies from ntfs to ext3. `-a` is equal to `-rlptgoD`. I'd recomment to use `-vrltD`

Answer (score 0):

You can move `mv` or copy `cp` your files.

I recomment you to make a new folder on your partition

```
sudo mkdir /backup/FileServer
```

If you want to give you all the rights to this new folder, make yourself as the owner

```
sudo chown $USER:$USER /backup/FileServer -R
```

Then you can copy the whole folder:

```
cp -r /FileServer /backup/FileServer
```

or move the whole folder:

```
mv /FileServer /backup/FileServer
```

---

If you want to understand the comands given, enter `man chmod` to read the manual. To exit the manual you can press <kbd>q</kbd>

Comment: I think I worded my question wrongly or I'm not understanding. I'd like to keep the /FileServer name, but move it to my /dev/sdc1(I realized it's not partitioned...) Sorry for the noob question/wording.

Comment: what do you get when you enter `lsblk -f`

Comment: Have you edit the fstab file by hand?

Comment: `mcpc@mcpc:~$ lsblk -f
NAME   FSTYPE   LABEL UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT  
loop0  squashfs                                            /snap/core/7396  
loop1  squashfs                                            /snap/core/7270  
sda  
├─sda1  
└─sda2 ext4           4b7435dd-e74c-4aef-95ae-94591c8fef63 /  
sdb  
├─sdb1 vfat           6BB0-42CC  
└─sdb2 ntfs     Media 3468548E6854512A                     /FileServer  
sdc  
└─sdc1`  
  
and yes, I edited fstab by hand. I just formatted and partitioned my 2TB as you can see. But I currenlty don't have it mounted.